# Linq Expression - Invalid Arguments

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, func, linq-expressions

```
public class EcImageWrapper
{

    //etc...

    public IQueryable<EcFieldWrapper> ListOfFields
    {
        get
        {
            //logic here

            return this.listOfFields.AsQueryable();
        }
    }

    public EcFieldWrapper FindBy(Expression<Func<EcFieldWrapper, int, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return this.ListOfFields.Where(predicate).SingleOrDefault();
    }

    public EcFieldWrapper FindByName(string fieldName)
    {
        return this.FindBy(x => x.Name.ToUpper() == fieldName.ToUpper());
        //error here, wanting 3 arguments
        //which makes sense as the above Expression has 3
        //but i don't know how to get around this
    }
```

For some reason the Expression> Is requiring me to use 3 arguments, in the past I've only used 2 for the instance in question. However, now I'm wanting to do a find by on a collection within this instance.

I'm getting the following errors:

```
Delegate 'System.Func<MSDORCaptureUE.Wrappers.EcFieldWrapper,int,bool>' does not take 1 arguments
The best overloaded method match for 'CaptureUE.Wrappers.EcImageWrapper.FindBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<CaptureUE.Wrappers.EcFieldWrapper,int,bool>>)' has some invalid arguments
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<CaptureUE.Wrappers.EcFieldWrapper,int,bool>>'
```

Desired outcome:
To be able to use a predicate of the return type EcFieldWrapper and predicate type of EcFieldWrapper within the instance of a class EcImageWrapper

Why does it require 3? Why the int?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "the expression is requiring me to use three arguments"? What happens if you change your method to just an `Expression<Func<EcFieldWrapper, bool>>`?

Comment: Hrm... I could have sworn this threw an error when i did this earlier. It seems to not be throwing an error now when i try it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The existing method doesn't require 3 arguments - it requires an `Expression<Func<EcFieldWrapper, int, bool>>` because that's what you've declared your method to accept. That would be something like:

```
// This version ignores the index, but you could use it if you wanted to.
(value, index) => value.Name.ToUpper() == fieldName.ToUpper()
```

The `index` would be the position within the collection, as you're calling [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548547.aspx) of `Queryable.Where`.

Assuming you don't want the index, I strongly suspect you just want to change your `FindBy` method to:

```
public EcFieldWrapper FindBy(Expression<Func<EcFieldWrapper, bool>> predicate)
{
    return this.ListOfFields.Where(predicate).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Or more simply, using the overload of `SingleOrDefault` which accepts a predicate:

```
public EcFieldWrapper FindBy(Expression<Func<EcFieldWrapper, bool>> predicate)
{
    return this.ListOfFields.SingleOrDefault(predicate);
}
```

That should work fine - and if it doesn't, you should tell us what happens when you try it.

Comment: Thanks... I'll give it a try and accept your answer when done.

Comment: What would be the difference of .Where(predicate).SingleOrDefault() and .SingleOrDefault(predicate)? Is there a performance increase? How does it handle each call differently?

Comment: @bizah: I'd expect them to be converted into the same SQL, so no performance difference.

Answer (score 0):

No need for `Find` method.  Do everything in `FindByName`.

```
public EcFieldWrapper FindByName(string fieldName)
{
    fieldName = fieldName.ToUpper();
    return ListOfFields
       .SingleOrDefeault(x => x.Name.ToUpper() == fieldName);
}
```

Comment: FindByName was originally done this way. However, this was a way for me to test local to the class and I would much prefer to have the FindBy which is dynamic for all predicates versus just having support for the name property.